# Avoid repeating the same page for several products

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I have a list of product names and their image, as I want to avoid repeating the same page for several products. I'm doing the following:

I am passing the a variable `id` the name I want to appear in the products.php page so for example I am using  `products.php?id=anyname`  and use `$_GET` to know the id name variable. Then I am populating a menu with an array wich contains all the names I need

For example the in the menu I will have displayed :

`key:  gfon`  and the `value: Fondant pt`

and then an image with gfon.png will be loaded

This is the code

```
<li>
        <a href="menu.html" style="padding:8px 30px;">THE MAIN MENU</a>
        <ul>                

<?php
   if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
       $product = $_GET['id'];
   }

  $array = array(
    "gfon"  => "Fondant pt",
    "galf"  => "Alfajores gy",
    "gdom"  => "Domino tre",
    "gesp"  => "Espiral ere",
    "gsan"  => "Sandwich  we ",
    );

   foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/products.php?id=".$key."\">".$val."</a>    </li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Then comes the section which will change a picture depending on the product chosen

```
<?php 
echo "<h1>";
switch ($product) {
      case "gfon":
      echo "Fondant</h1>";          
      break;

      case "galf":
      echo "Alfajores</h1>";
      break;

      case "gdom":
      echo "Domino</h1>";
      break;

      case "gesp":
      echo "Espiral</h1>";
      break;            


     case "gsan":
     echo "Sandwich</h1>";
     break;         

}
echo "<p> <a href=\"http://www.mysite.com\"><img src=\"images/".$product.".png\" alt=\"" .$product." width=\"300\" height=\"300\" align=\"right\"/> </a>"

?>
```

Sometimes it is working and sometimes not, I am getting this error occassionally

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
>   you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Also I do not have access to the log file :( is there any better way to go to solve the this?

Comment: "Also I do not have access to the log file" --- how is it possible?

Comment: I rented the hosting of my webpage, so I just can have access to the httpdocs....

Comment: what about $product variable. If not set, h1 never ends. Then could be also problem including non-existing image as well.

Comment: @cMinor: so you pay money for service and don't even get log files?

Comment: well, I have to send a mail asking for that :S...

Comment: Is there a specific ID that causes the error or a particular scenario?  As a side note, if you use single quotes around your strings you don't need to escape double quotes in your html.  Example: `$link = '<a href="http://mysite.com">Link to my site</a>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to check the server logs for the specific problem but there is also problems with your code here are some changes.

```
<?php 
// Define your array before checking the $_GET['id']
$array = array(
"gfon"  => "Fondant pt",
"galf"  => "Alfajores gy",
"gdom"  => "Domino tre",
"gesp"  => "Espiral ere",
"gsan"  => "Sandwich  we ",
);
// Check that the id is in the array as a key and assign your product var, else set as null
$product = (isset($_GET['id']) && array_key_exists($_GET['id'],$array)) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

// Output your html
?>
<li>
    <a href="menu.html" style="padding:8px 30px;">THE MAIN MENU</a>
    <ul>                
    <?php foreach($array as $key=>$val):?>
        <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com/products.php?id=<?=$key?>"><?=$val?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</li>

<?php 
// Replacing the switch statement with a simple if else
// Is $product not null? ok it must be within the array
if($product !== null){
    // Use explode to chop up the string and grab the first value.
    echo '<h1>'.explode(' ',$array[$product])[0].'</h1>';
    echo '<p><a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="images/'.$product.'.png" alt="'.$product.'" width="300" height="300" align="right" /></a>';
}else{
    // Echo something default
    echo '<h1>Default</h1>';
    echo '<p><a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="images/default.png" alt="" width="300" height="300" align="right" /></a>';
}
?>
```

I noticed `alt=\"" .$product." width=\"300\"` would effect your output as your not closing the alt attribute.